# Swift - How can i load a function only once?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, function, timer

I want to make a app, where you are getting 1 point each second, and it all works fine. But since i have multiple view controllers, then timer runs again, and gives 2 points per second. How can i fix that?

The code:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  TapTap
//
//  Created by Jonas Boutrup on 10/02/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Jonas Boutrup. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //initialize your realm
    let realm = try! Realm()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        loadpoints()
        startAddPoints()
        print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.path!)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var pointLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bonusPointLabel: UILabel!

    var points = 0
    var bonusPoints = 0
    var multiplierClick = 0
    var pointsPerSecond = 1
    var timer = NSTimer()

    func loadpoints() {

        //check if there is a Click with id == 1
        if let clickWithId1 = realm.objects(Click).filter("id == 1").first {
            self.points = clickWithId1.totalPoints
            self.bonusPoints = clickWithId1.totalBonusPoints
            self.multiplierClick = clickWithId1.multiplierClick
            self.pointsPerSecond = clickWithId1.pointsPerSecond
        } else {  // if there is no Click with id == 1, create it and add it to realm
            let click = Click()
            click.id = 1
            click.totalBonusPoints = 0
            click.totalPoints = 0
            click.multiplierClick = 1
            click.timesTwoPrice = 20
            click.pointsPerSecond = 1
            self.points = click.totalPoints
            self.bonusPoints = click.totalBonusPoints

            do {
                try realm.write {
                    realm.add(click, update: true)
                }

            } catch {}
        }
        self.pointLabel.text = "\(points)"
        self.bonusPointLabel.text = "\(bonusPoints)"
    }

    func startAddPoints() {
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target:self, selector: Selector("addPoints"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }



    func addPoints() {
        //check if there is a Click with id == 1
        if let clickWithId1 = realm.objects(Click).filter("id == 1").first {

            do {
                //if there is a Click with id == 1, increment its totalclicks by 1 and update it

                try realm.write {
                    clickWithId1.totalPoints += clickWithId1.pointsPerSecond
                    realm.add(clickWithId1, update: true)
                }

            } catch {}

            loadpoints()

        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        //check if there is a Click with id == 1
        if let clickWithId1 = realm.objects(Click).filter("id == 1").first {

            do {
                //if there is a Click with id == 1, increment its totalclicks by 1 and update it

                try realm.write {
                    clickWithId1.totalPoints += clickWithId1.multiplierClick
                    realm.add(clickWithId1, update: true)
                }

                self.points = clickWithId1.totalPoints
                self.pointLabel.text = "\(points)"
                let roll = arc4random_uniform(100) + 1
                print("\(roll)")

                if roll == 14 {
                    try realm.write {
                        clickWithId1.totalBonusPoints += 1
                        self.bonusPoints = clickWithId1.totalBonusPoints
                        self.bonusPointLabel.text = "\(bonusPoints)"
                        realm.add(clickWithId1, update: true)
                    }
                }

            } catch {}
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance! :D

**EDIT**

I found a solution to it! You need to have a button that stops the timer!

```
@IBAction func stopTimer(sender: AnyObject) {  
        timer.invalidate()   
    }
```

Comment: See [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best would be call the timer from one place only (for example another class which is not a VC and accessible globally or app delegate). Another option could be to invalidate a timer every time you leave a view controller, so there is only one timer that works at a time. Yet another option could be to have an instance of `NSTimer` passed as a parameter in the `addPoints` function so you can check for a particular timer object. There is a number of ways, but ideally you would have only one timer.